# Local special ingredients on Cape Cod

Tags: regional-cuisine

I will be spending some time on Cape Cod and since I'm from a landlocked country, I wonder what local ingredients I could take advantage when cooking during my stay. I suppose seafood and fish are in good supply, though probably still not cheap. Is there anything else worth hunting for? What are some typical dishes in the wider area utilizing local ingredients?

Comment: What season are you visiting during? Seafood is the most obvious ingredient, perhaps lobsters or clam chowder. Cranberries also come to mind, but they are much more dependent on season/weather. Searching for "New England" recipes is likely to lead you to some interesting ideas, but I honestly can't think of much that's highly local to Massachusetts and/or not widely available elsewhere.

Comment: It will be the end of the summer. Lobsters are a good suggestion, I thought they might be more of a Maine thing. How about shrimp? Can I expect seafood to be reasonable prices say in comparison with pork or beef?

Comment: "Maine lobsters" can actually be found all over New England. Shrimp I think is more prevalent in southern states (e.g. Louisiana, South Carolina). Prices might be better if you avoid restaurants -- ask some locals where they get their seafood -- but at the peak of tourist season, lobsters will be pricey. Fish might be a better option.

Comment: Hello VoY. As with most StackExchange sites, questions which result in list-style answers are not accepted. As there is no way to enumerate all possible Cape Cod local ingredients, or to distinguish between them (X is more of a Cape Cod ingredient than Y!), they just don't work with our voting system. I will remove the recommendations tag too, if it applies to a question, this is a clear sign it isn't suitable for the site.

Comment: I understand. How do you suggest I rephrase the question so that I can learn about my subject using the QA format?

Answer (score 1):

When I lived in Boston, and occasionally visited the Cape Cod area, there was more of a regional cuisine than local ingredients. Seafood -- lobster, fish, clams, mussels -- is the most uniquely Cape Cod ingredient I can think of, since it is right on the coast.

[This infographic](http://www.mapsofworld.com/pages/mmmerica/infographic-of-cuisine-of-new-england/) describes some of the foods that are associated with New England, although that is a little too general for your question -- dairy, for example, is much more a Vermont or non-coastal ingredient. However, Cape Cod is close enough that Vermont cheddar will be quite easy to come by!